# Ati Graphics driver on 14.04.4

Tags: ati

Having a really bad day on first day of Linux. So after installing 14.04.4, I downloaded ATI Graphics driver and install it, and turns out some error message saying "System occur low Graphics" and stuff, can't really recall the exact error. I tried to google it, but it was so hard to get around it for someone like me who is new. Secondly, I can't able to install steam either, showing me some error.

Should I install older version of Ubuntu like 14.04.03 or move back to Windows which I don't want to?

```
<code>harsh@harsh-desktop:~$ sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
[sudo] password for harsh: 
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-amdcccle-updates.
(Reading database ... 198082 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack fglrx-amdcccle-updates_15.201-0ubuntu2~15.10.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fglrx-amdcccle-updates (2:15.201-0ubuntu2~15.10.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-updates.
Preparing to unpack fglrx-updates_15.201-0ubuntu2~15.10.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fglrx-updates (2:15.201-0ubuntu2~15.10.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-updates-core.
Preparing to unpack fglrx-updates-core_15.201-0ubuntu2~15.10.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fglrx-updates-core (2:15.201-0ubuntu2~15.10.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fglrx-updates-core:
 fglrx-updates-core depends on gcc-4.9; however:
  Package gcc-4.9 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package fglrx-updates-core (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fglrx-updates:
 fglrx-updates depends on fglrx-updates-core; however:
  Package fglrx-updates-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package fglrx-updates (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fglrx-amdcccle-updates:
 fglrx-amdcccle-updates depends on fglrx-updates; however:
  Package fglrx-updates is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package fglrx-amdcccle-updates (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fglrx-updates-core
 fglrx-updates
 fglrx-amdcccle-updates
harsh@harsh-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dkms fakeroot libfakeroot
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  fglrx-amdcccle-updates fglrx-updates fglrx-updates-core
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 428 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 198343 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing fglrx-amdcccle-updates (2:15.201-0ubuntu2~15.10.2) ...
Removing fglrx-updates (2:15.201-0ubuntu2~15.10.2) ...
Removing fglrx-updates-core (2:15.201-0ubuntu2~15.10.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.7) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-30-generic
harsh@harsh-desktop:~$ 

</code>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36539/discussion-on-question-by-smokylicious-ati-graphics-driver-on-14-04-4).

Comment: I updated the answer. You need to run the two last commands. The driver did not install.

Comment: After running both last commands, I am not sure what happened. I restarted and searched for ATI or AMD in dash search and still nothing showed up. I have updated my post with the output of what I got after those last 2 commands.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9`

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gcc-4.9 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gcc-4.9' has no installation candidate

Comment: I just opened terminal and wrote that command, should I run all those commands again, all those 4 commands and adding this to the last?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Canonical people did not update fglrx driver for kernel 4.2 in `trusty` repositories.

I suggest installing it from `wily` this way. Run in terminal

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/f/fglrx-installer-updates/fglrx-updates_15.201-0ubuntu2~15.10.2_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/f/fglrx-installer-updates/fglrx-updates-core_15.201-0ubuntu2~15.10.2_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/f/fglrx-installer-updates/fglrx-amdcccle-updates_15.201-0ubuntu2~15.10.2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
```

If there are any errors, please tell me. If not, reboot and test.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this problem. First you need to grab the latest driver from the ATI website, but make sure to select Linux x86_64 or Linux x86 instead of Ubuntu x86_64 or Ubuntu x86. 
[Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExsrW.jpg)

before installing, I highly recommend to un-install ATI driver.

You can also check out this video, it really helps : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tc8s5yhylbo